# Smallest radius sphere intersect with the quadric surface

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization, maxima-minima

There is a sphere equation:

$${x_1}^2 + {x_2}^2 + {x_3}^2 = R^2.$$

A quadratic surface, given by level $C$ and a set of parameters $a, e, i$, has formula:

$$a {x_1}^2 + e {x_2}^2 + i {x_3}^2 + C = 0.$$

This equation can be rewritten with the help of the diagonal matrix $M$, on the diagonal of which there are arbitrary numbers, as follows:

[image: Elements b,c,d,f,h,i are equal to zero]

Elements $\ b,c,d,f,g,h$ are equal to zero.

In 3D (actually in general) what we are looking for is the smallest radius sphere centered at the origin that intersects with the quadric surface defined by a given level set from the quadratic form defined by the symmetric matrix $M$.

Is it possible to solve this problem analytically for the components of the vector $x$ using methods from differential geometry?

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207732/solve-the-vector-matrix-equation-minimize-the-length-of-the-desired-n-dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of the smallest intersecting sphere is simply the distance from the quadric to the origin:

$$R^2 = \min_{x}\ \|x\|^2 \quad \mathrm{s.t.}\quad x^TMx = -C.$$

Assuming that $C>0$, notice that his quadratically-constrained quadratic program is of Rayleigh-quotient type, and can be rewritten as
$$R^2 = \min_x\ \frac{\|x\|^2}{x^T (-M/C) x}\quad \mathrm{s.t.}\quad x^TMx < 0$$
or
$$R^{-2} = \max_x\ \frac{x^T (-M/C) x}{\|x\|^2}\quad \mathrm{s.t.}\quad x^TMx < 0.$$
The solution radius will be $R^2 = -C/\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the most-negative eigenvalue of $M$ (or no solution, if $M$ is positive-definite) and the direction $x$ of the intersection point is given by the corresponding eigenvector. When $M$ is diagonal, $\lambda$ is simply the most-negative diagonal entry.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: 1. If the matrix M is not diagonal (one of the elements of the diagonal is zero or are there other elements of the matrix that are not equal to zero and not lying on the diagonal), then what will the solution look like in this case?
Such questions have arisen so far.

Comment: 2. Is the understanding correct that if there is a correspondence between the sign of the elements on the diagonal of the matrix M and the sign of the constant C (that is, the negative elements on the diagonal of the matrix M correspond only to negative values ​​of C and vice versa - "positive - positive"), then the problem is solvable in this case?

Comment: The fact is that in your answer there are several concepts and tools that are new to me, with which i was not familiar before.

Comment: 1. If one of the elements of the diagonal is zero, the solution is trivially (0,0,0). Off-diagonal terms mean that you need to compute the eigenvalue and eigenvector, rather than just looking at the matrix diagonal entries. 2. Right.

Comment: Thank you! Now I will try to deal with the calculations. Let's see what happens.