# Real-time calculation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

Are there ways to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors in real time for implementation on the control microprocessor?

I start from the questions that users helped me solve in the following topics:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207732/solve-the-vector-matrix-equation-minimize-the-length-of-the-desired-n-dimension/207752?noredirect=1#comment533606_207752

[Smallest radius sphere intersect with the quadric surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3437620/smallest-radius-sphere-intersect-with-the-quadric-surface/3437632?noredirect=1#comment7067595_3437632)

From these methods, the need arises for calculating the eigenvalues and vectors in real time to control some object.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "calculating in real time"?

Comment: If you follow the links, then in those problems you can see that the length of the vector x was minimized for the constant C. "Calculations in real time" - we are talking about the fact that the constant C changes in time, and the controller automatically selects the components of the vector so that minimize its length (in accordance with the algorithms for the links).

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "What is the rate?" ?

Comment: At the moment, i can answer this way: processor frequency is 16 MHz, and all its resources can be used to calculate eigenvalues.

Comment: 1. "can be broken..." - but it is no broken.You can go through them and see the background that is represented there.
2. "I am not sure...what exact problem to solve" - And I am sure that the question was identified at the beginning of this topic. "...calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors in real time for implementation on the control microprocessor".
But how to solve this issue is a continuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 'real-time calculation' I understand that the algorithm has to be fast enough for real problem solutions involving short times. Because you are using a microcontroller, you should look for an algorithm in C.

There's a book called "Numerical Recipes in C" that has information on how to do this if you want to program it yourself.
If you want to use LAPACK (Linear Algebra Package), actually the function DGEEV that computes that for you, you can take a look at the [official documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/d8e/group__double_g_eeigen_ga66e19253344358f5dee1e60502b9e96f.html) for it. It's written in Fortran, so you might want to re-write it or find it in C. [Here](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/dgeev_ex.c.htm) you can find it written in C, and you can adapt it.

---

Apart from the apparent coding implementation of the algorithm that you are going to use, if you are interested in the mathematics behind eigenvectors and eigenvalue computation, several books explain it.

A few that I personally like are:

- *Golub and Van Loan - Matrix Computations*. Chapter 7 starts with the unsymmetric eigenvalue problem and gives several methods that allow you to compute eigenvalues: *Power Method, Orthogonal Iteration, QR and LR Iterations*, etc.
- Similar to that one, you have *Demmel - Applied Numerical Linear Algebra*, which I (personally) like more than the one above, but both are great. Chapter 4 also starts with the unsymmetric eigenvalue problem and how to approach it via direct methods.
- Another good book would be *Trefeten and Bau - Numerical Linear Algebra* that approaches the eigenvalue problem in lecture 24, part 5.
- *Horn and Johnson - Matrix Analysis*. It's more on the analysis side, so it may be more useful if you want to set a basis for a broader understanding of the algorithms.

Apart from that, because it's a coding problem, I would recommend that you take a look at Numerical Recipes in C. Also, BLAS and LAPACK could help you implement it.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your attention to the issue. I had such a book.
I want to clarify: I am mainly interested in mathematics in this problem. I will implement the program myself. Can you advise literature, which deals not with programmatic, but with mathematical aspects of solving these problems in real time?

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on what you can do with the microcontroller?

Comment: There are no practical restrictions, as while there are no special requirements for speed of calculations, and memory is enough.
Unless, there is a restriction on the type of mathematical operations.
The implementation of mathematics cannot go beyond +, -, *, ÷ and logical operations.

Comment: I updated the answer with a few references that could help you with the mathematical part of the problem, @AndySol

Comment: Thank you very much!